# Building my app with Expo causes extra padding on the top of my app's screen (React Native)

Tags: react-native, build, expo, padding

I'm building my first app with React Native and I'm using Expo to build my app. My problem is whenever I build my app there comes this extra white space / padding on top of my app. I have tried using SafeAreaView with flex: 1 but it doesn't fix the issue. Has anyone had this kind of issue before?

[image: extra padding]

Comment: Did you find any solution? I got same issue after i migrate to expo SDK version 46.

Comment: Same, Im seeing the same issue on sdk 45. Keen to know if anyone has found any solutions for this as well

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it using StatusBar component inside my header title component

See:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Adding this to App.tsx solved it for me:

```
Platform.OS === "android" && StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("transparent");
Platform.OS === "android" && StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the Android StatusBar.

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/configuring-statusbar/

> androidStatusBar.translucent
> Value type - boolean. This option can be used to specify whether the
> status bar should be translucent. When false, the system status bar
> pushes the content of your app down (similar to position: relative).
> When true, the status bar floats above the content in your app
> (similar to position: absolute).

So I updated app.json, adding:

```
"androidStatusBar": {
  "backgroundColor": "#00000000",
  "translucent": true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

What happened to me, is that I forgot to setup the expo-router. You need to use the property `headerShown: false`.

in my scenario, thats how it goes: [screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2M5C.png)

Comment: Please read [why we ask that you not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933).  Please 

[Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78239917/edit)

to include the text in-addition-to or in-place-of the image.  Thanks!